# Deploy and run grunt server on IBM bluemix

Tags: angularjs, node.js, ibm-cloud

What changes do I have to make inorder to actually run a successful build and host my website on bluemix?

Right now, this is my Gruntfile.js, manifest.yml and package.json. The base folder 'app' is an Angular application -

```
     module.exports = function(grunt){
          grunt.initConfig({
            connect: {
              server: {
                options: {
                  port: 9000,
                  base: 'app',
                  keepalive: true,
                }
              }
            }
          });
          grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-connect');

          grunt.registerTask('default', ['connect']);
        };
```

`package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "dummy",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {"grunt-cli": "^1.2.0",
    "grunt": "^0.4.5",
    "grunt-contrib-connect": "^0.10.1"
  }

}
```

`manifest.yml`:

```
---
applications: #Reference http://docs.cloudfoundry.com/docs/using/deploying-apps/manifest.html
- name: dummy #Application Name. Unique to the user's Space
  memory: 256M #The maximum memory to allocate to each application instance
  instances: 1 #The number of instances of the application to start
  path: ./ #Path to the application to be pushed
  command:  npm install && node_modules/.bin/grunt serve #The command to use to start the application
```

Comment: Have you already tried pushing the app to Bluemix? What errors did you get, or what wasn't working?

Comment: Starting your application with command : " node_modules/.bin/grunt serve" might resolve your issue . https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/25856/how-to-deploy-a-web-app-based-on-grunt/

Comment: Apparently, I dont have a node_modules.......

Comment: so I removed all my dev dependencies and placed it into dependencies, including grunt-cli and changed my run command to "npm install && node_modules/.bin/grunt serve". But still it doesn't work. Deploy fails.

Answer (score 2):

Few suggestions when working with node applications and Bluemix:

1. To start a node application it's recommended to use `npm start` and specify the script in the `package.json`.
2. If your application needs to build assets, specify how to do that in the `postinstall` script in the `package.json`. For example if you are using [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) and your main task is `build` you will have something like:

   ```
   "postinstall": "gulp build"
   ```
3. When running in Bluemix `VCAP_APP_HOST` and `VCAP_APP_PORT` will have the host and port where your application will run.

---

The files below have the fixes mentioned above:

`manifest.yml`:

```
---
applications:
- name: dummy-kartik-yadav
  memory: 512M
  instances: 1
  path: .
  command: npm start
```

`package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "dummy",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node_modules/.bin/grunt serve",
    "postinstall": "console.log('build ui assets like js, css, html...')"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "grunt-cli": "^1.2.0",
    "grunt": "^0.4.5",
    "grunt-contrib-connect": "^0.10.1"
  }
}
```

`gruntfile.js`:

```
module.exports = function(grunt){
  grunt.initConfig({
    connect: {
      server: {
        options: {
          port: process.env.VCAP_APP_PORT || 9000, # listen to the port that bluemix will assign you
          base: 'app',
          keepalive: true
        }
      }
    }
  });
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-connect');
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['connect']);
};
```

After doing the changes mentioned above, open the project folder and run `npm start`. If it works locally, it will  in Bluemix.